# skimage segmetation extracting labels filtered by properties

Tags: python, vectorization, image-segmentation, scikit-image, feature-extraction

I would like to extract skimage identified "labels" or segments which meet thresholds of parameters. My binary image was successfully split into segments, which skimage seems to call "labels", as the following:

```
labels = measure.label(classified, connectivity = image.ndim)

#symoblize each label with a different colour and plot it over the original image
image_label_overlay = label2rgb(labels, image=image)
plt.imshow(image_label_overlay)
```

[image]

As you can see, each labels are individually coloured.

My question is: How can I select these labeled segments base on their properties, and vectorize them in some way (convert to geopandas dataframe entries or something). My attempt to plot filtered labels is as follows, but was unsuccessful:

```
props = measure.regionprops_table(labels, image,
                                      properties = ['label',
                                                   'area',
                                                   'eccentricity',
                                                   'perimeter',
                                                   'equivalent_diameter',
                                                   'mean_intensity',
                                                   'solidity'])

#create a dataframe from these object properties
segs = pd.DataFrame(props)

#extract segments of low eccentricity (0 would be a perfect circle)
segs_filtered =segs[segs['eccentricity'] < 0.1]

#create list of label indexed meeting criteria
filtered_labels = segs_filtered['label']
```

I think `filtered labels` is actually indexing the pixels that belong to the labels I want to keep instead of the labels as a whole. That is why the following plotting method doesn't work.

```
fig = px.imshow(labels, binary_string=True)
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip') # hover is only for label info

# For each label, add a filled scatter trace for its contour,
# and display the properties of the label in the hover of this trace.
for index in filtered_labels:
    label_i = props[index].label
    contour = measure.find_contours(labels == label_i, 0.5)[0]
    y, x = contour.T
    hoverinfo = ''
    for prop_name in properties:
        hoverinfo += f'<b>{prop_name}: {getattr(props[index], prop_name):.2f}</b><br>'
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y, name=label_i,
        mode='lines', fill='toself', showlegend=False,
        hovertemplate=hoverinfo, hoveron='points+fills'))

plotly.io.show(fig)
```

`label_i = props[index].label` produces a `Key error: 1`

Please let me know if there is a way of filtering and producing vector objects from these labels.

For reproducibility[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L-8Q4Y6ion9pNQlZtx5g0YxHzyA9pWq9/view?usp=sharing), here is the classified tiff "classified" that is input:

Also I am sorry if this is unclear. I don't really understand how the labelling and properties work in skimage.

Thanks very much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the issue is that `props` is the output from `regionprops_table`, which is a dictionary mapping column names to columns of values. (You can see this by looking at the API documentation [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops_table).) Since you don't have a column called 1, (the columns are 'label', 'eccentricity', etc.) you get the KeyError.

It looks to me like you've mixed examples of [`regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops), which returns a list of regions, and [`regionprops_table`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops-table), which returns a dictionary of columns: `props[index].label` is what you would do if you were iterating over the list of regions, as is `getattr(props[index], prop_name)`.

If you just want to plot, then probably you should just use `regionprops`, and bring the filtering into the for-loop:

```py
prop_names = [
        'label','area','eccentricity','perimeter',
        'equivalent_diameter','mean_intensity','solidity',
        ])
props = measure.regionprops(labels, image)

fig = px.imshow(labels, binary_string=True)
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip') # hover is only for label info

for prop in props:
    if prop.eccentricity < 0.1:  # or whatever filtering you want to do
        label_i = prop.label
        # find the bbox in the props image and add offset, much faster than
        # using full image
        contour = measure.find_contours(prop.image, 0.5)[0] + props.bbox[:2]
        y, x = contour.T
        hoverinfo = ''
        for prop_name in prop_names:
            hoverinfo += f'<b>{prop_name}: {getattr(prop, prop_name):.2f}</b><br>'
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=x, y=y, name=label_i,
                mode='lines', fill='toself', showlegend=False,
                hovertemplate=hoverinfo, hoveron='points+fills'
                ))
plotly.io.show(fig)
```

Comment: Ahh thank  for the insight, that first part I didn't understand until now. Is label_i = prop.label selecting the labels which meet the filter criteria? I wasn't aware that it was possible to index the  labels other than in the form of their index values within the dictionary. The `labels` variable itself confused me because it was really just a numpy array where pixel values were numbered by cluster.

Comment: "just a numpy array where pixel values were numbered by cluster" yeah, we try to refer to it as "label_image" inside scikit-image because of this confusion, but it might not be 100% consistent everywhere. "in the form of their index values within the dictionary" — note that the output of regionprops is a *list*, not a dictionary, which is indeed confusing. The position j on the list is the jth nonzero label in the label_image. ie if you have labels 45, 77, and 82 in the label_image, you will get a list where element 0 will be the properties of label 45, element 1 for 77, and 2 for 82.